# comprehension and variables scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have the following:

```
x = 3
l = [x+x for x in range(10)]
```

is there a way to make any of the two variable (in the `(x+x)`) refer to the `x` variable declared outer? Or Can't I?

I mean with function I can refer to the outer variable using `global` or `nonlocal`, here is there a solution?

Comment: Why don't you use a different name for the loop variable?!

Comment: or the outer variable ... but the x in the list comprehension shadows the outer x

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know I know I know that I can use another name, it's obvious, but I want to know if there is another way which I might not know.

Comment: @antox there is no way a name can refer to two different objects in the same scope.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okkey :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different variable name

```
>>> i = 3
>>> l = [i+x for x in range(10)]
>>> l
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The way you have it written, it will [name shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: Technically in this case it is not shadowing but actually overwriting the original variable. Shadowing would be the case if x were defined in a higher level scope.

Comment: In Python 3 it is shadowing, because list comprehensions have their own scopes (technically they run in an invisible function). In Python 2 you would be correct, that the `x` from the list comprehension will overwrite the `x` outside (but that's not true for generator expressions, or dictionary or set comprehensions).